# Configure NetBeans to execute single unit tests with JMockit as javaagent

Tags: netbeans, maven-surefire-plugin, jmockit, javaagents, maven-dependency-plugin

When using JMockit with Maven for unit tests, it is required to pass the location of `jmockit.jar` to the VM by setting the `-javaagent` parameter. The `maven-dependency-plugin` can do this automatically, I have set up a configuration that does the expected like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${dependency.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>properties</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-javaagent:${org.jmockit:jmockit:jar}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This works when the test suite and also single tests are called from command line, e.g. by

```
mvn test -Dtest=MyClass#someTest
```

From within NetBeans it is also possible to run the whole test suite (e.g. when "Clean and Build" is executed). But when a single file is tested, the path is not injected. There is a command like the following in the log when the VM crashes:

```
Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/kap && /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64/jre/bin/java '-javaagent:${org.jmockit:jmockit:jar}' -jar ...
```

i.e. the placeholder is not filled with the correct location. In contrast, a call on the command line produces

```
[DEBUG] Forking command line: /bin/sh -c cd /home/kap/ && /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64/jre/bin/java -javaagent:/home/kap/.m2/repository/org/jmockit/jmockit/1.49/jmockit-1.49.jar
```

It is especially weird that it works with the whole test suite, but not for single tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why does the single test fail?

When executing `clean and build` NetBeans by default executes `mvn clean install`. So the maven executes the goal `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:properties` during its normal build lifecycle and the plugin creates variable `${org.jmockit:jmockit:jar}`.

When executing single test file (i.e. `Project -> TestFile -> RightClick -> Test File` (or Ctl+F6)) NetBeans executes **only single** goal `mvn -Dtest=MyClass#someTest surefire:test`. So the maven-dependency-plugin:properties doesn't execute at all and maven could not find the variable `${org.jmockit:jmockit:jar}` because it was not been created.

## How to solve it?

### Option 1.

Go to `Project -> Properties -> Actions`  and for actions Test File set options to execute goal as follows:

```
test-compile org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:properties surefire:test
```

[image]

NetBeans creates the nbactions.xml file so the solution would work only when executing a single test from NetBeans.

### Option 2.

Remove maven-dependency-plugin from you pom.xm. Instead specify the location to jmockit.jar using `${settings.localRepository}` [property](https://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Introduction.html#maven):

```
    ...
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <jmockit.version>1.43</jmockit.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"/org/jmockit/jmockit/${jmockit.version}/jmockit-${jmockit.version}.jar</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
```

### Option 3.

I would assume binding the properties goal to the test-compile phase of maven but it would only work if disabling the Compile On Save feature of NetBeans.

```
...
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
     <phase>test-compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>properties</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
...
```